# Issue with String response in Retrofit

Tags: php, android, retrofit

I am using Retrofit in my android app to communicate with my server. In one of my server calls I am expecting a String response from server. So, I declare a callback which expects a string value. `Callback<String>`. In the php, I echo a string. Say `echo "test";` When I hit the url in browser, the echo works as expected `test`. But in my android app, failure callback is called.
I tried changing the php to `echo "\"test\"";`
On browser : `"test"`
On android : success callback is called.

I solved it by declaring a variable.
Php:

```
$result = "test";
echo $result;
```

Browser: `test`

Android : success callback is called.

My question is, is this how Retrofit works? Or am I doing anything wrong? Also, to solve this is there any way other than declaring a variable?

Answer (score 0):

`Callback<String>` does not make a lot of sense in the context of retrofit. By default retrofit operates using GSON.

What you are actually waiting for from the server is json deserialized into a POJO (simple java object).

Lets say you have a data model (POJO) like:

```
public class User {
    public final String name;
}
```

Then you'd use a callback like this `Callback<User>`. And from the server you should do: `echo '{ "name" : "Simon" }';`

In your success callback you will have an instance of User class with the name field set to 'Simon'.

More on this here: http://square.github.io/retrofit/

Comment: I totally agree with you. I still wonder.. whats the difference between `echo "test"` and `$result = "test"; echo $result;` ? when using the former, failure callback is called and when using latter, success callback is called.

Comment: The problem is that "test" is actually valid json. It's a json string. And test is nothing in the context of json.